# How can i move button to center

Tags: css, button, alignment, center

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8orM.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b19Xt.png

Why not button is align center and the text "CV" is not in the same row with Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you have a button and an arrow below like that, I would think it has to do with your divs

For example

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button>
     Download Cv
  </button>
</div>
<div class="cv-arrow">
Data
</div>
```

But if you are looking for a real proven answer, it would be best if you posted a html and css snippet in stack overflow.

Comment: I have a div but i miss to add button there..... I stayed like an 1 hour to understand why is it look like that.Thanks you so much

Comment: Looking at your screenshots I did not really perfectly answer the question as my syntax was in raw html. But typically when a problem is solved you should click the checkmark to approve the answer, this lets people know the question has an answer and helps build your reputation

Comment: It's work but i need to add justify content center and align-items center to be perfect in the center